# Bureaucracy based on Internet

Tags: government, internet

I am currently writing a manual for a RPG game I am building in Python (computer programming language) and I want to have some lore behind it.

What would the effects of a Internet assisted government be like? I'm thinking it would result in PURE chaos because it can be easily manipulated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean "internet assisted government"? Is it government officials that use the internet to get information or using internet voting to make decisions or something else?

Comment: @sdrawkcabdear I think it's the reverse - that the government is sort of run BY the internet (I.e: Twitter direct representation) rather than elected officials vaguely informed THROUGH the internet...

Comment: @IsaacKotlicky, correct. The government IS represented by using TCP/IP and or Internet

Comment: I'm not sure if there is an answer here.  Personally, I can think of examples where it would become pure anarchy, examples where it would become a dictatorship, and examples where it could become a utopia.  The internet has a huge dynamic range from unreliable tools such as Twitter, to ultra-high-reliabiltiy found in cryptographic solutions like AES and public-key encryption.  Inbetween these extremes, we find strange dinosaurs like Wikipedia, which is somehow highly reliable despite an almost anarchistic approach to edits.

Comment: The more important factor would be *how* individuals influence the government.  Do they vote for how they want their dollars to be managed day by day, which would likely fail horridly?  If, instead, they have a similar level of input as they have today, it could work out as well as our current system.  That's not a technical question, but rather a social one.

Comment: Do we have pure chaos here, if take at example this particular resource, even less strict resources like 4chan (can't say less moderated) are not pure chaos. Spam bots trying to compromise different resources, can't say they do super well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well the real world results is giving bureaucrats access to the internet allows them to make a perfect hash of things even faster than before. The prime example is the rollout of the Obamacare Exchanges, which were announced with great fanfare and promptly crashed, leaving millions of people without access to even the most basic healthcare because they could not get in to purchase whatever mandated plan they were supposed to buy. Years and five billion (that is correct: *billion*) dollars later and they still don't have a fully functioning website, even though most small business can make or get a decent commercial website in a matter of days.

And of course, who can forget the massive data spills from government websites, ranging from Wikileaks to the theft of personal information of millions (yes, *millions*) of government employees and contractors with secret clearances by the Chinese over a *four year* period. China can now essentially wage war against *individual Americans*. And don't forget how a certain Presidential candidate maintained a mail server which she used to email classified and highly sensitive information outside of government scrutiny. If an Argentinian hacker can boast that he successfully hacked the server, it is a no brainer that the FSB and Chinese intelligence have been all through the information that was contained in the server. American foreign policy might be compromised for decades to come because of that.

And these same people who have neither the skill or apparently incentive to keep their own data secure also vacuum up *your* cellphone, email and social media data without a second thought.

So you might want to reconsider how much access to the internet you want governments to have...

Comment: @kommander0000 this is just tiny piece of story from one side,why to wish it